# SwiftUI – Trying to bind an action sheet visibility to a published var property

Tags: binding, swiftui

I am very new to SwiftUI. This is the first app I am creating using it.

I have this code:

```
class ActionSheetViewControl {
  enum ActionSheetType {
    case none
    case controlForm
    case suggestionForm
    case negativeForm
  }
  var type:ActionSheetType = .none
  var showActionSheet = false
  var shouldShowActionSheet:Bool {
    get {
      return showActionSheet && ((type == .controlForm) || (type == .suggestionForm))
    }
  }
}
```

The form should show just for two kinds of forms.

Then I have this on ContentView

```
class GlobalVariables: ObservableObject {
  @Published var actionControl: ActionSheetViewControl = ActionSheetViewControl()
}


@EnvironmentObject var globalVariables : GlobalVariables

// on body
.sheet(isPresented: XXXX,
       onDismiss: {
        
       }) {

}
```

what do I put on XXXX?

I have tried

```
globalVariables.actionSheetViewControl.shouldShowActionSheet
```

and also

```
globalVariables.actionSheetViewControl.$shouldShowActionSheet
```

or

```
$globalVariables.actionSheetViewControl.shouldShowActionSheet
```

and I get this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your ActionSheetViewControl to struct, so it is a value type.

```
struct ActionSheetViewControl {
```

Then in your ContentView, use it as following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var globalVariables : GlobalVariables

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            globalVariables.actionControl.showActionSheet = true
        })
        {
            Text("Open")
        }
    
        Text("Test")
            .sheet(isPresented: $globalVariables.actionControl.showActionSheet, content: {
                Text("Sheet")
            })
    }
    
}
```